# Create a deep object graph with Linq to XML, refactoring?

Tags: c#, refactoring, linq-to-xml

I am writing a simple XML file parser using LINQ to XML.

I want to have a TreeNode object (i.e a simple Tree structure) for each element in the XML. I want each element to be strongly typed.

It looks ugly and redundant compared to the simple looping approach I was using before (using System.XML). Is there a way to strip out the redundancies here?

```
        XElement ops = XElement.Load(@"c:\temp\exp.xml");
        Tree<Element> domain = new Tree<Element>();
        domain.Root = new TreeNode<Element>();
        var cells =
                    from cell in ops.Elements("cell")
                    select new
                    {
                        TreeNodeObj = new TreeNode<Element>
                            (new Cell((string)cell.Attribute("name"), (string)cell.Attribute("name"), null)),
                        XElem = cell
                    };
        foreach (var cell in cells)
        {
            domain.Root.AddChild(cell.TreeNodeObj);
            var agents =
                    from agent in cell.XElem.Elements("agent")
                    select new
                    {
                        TreeNodeObj = new TreeNode<Element>
                            (new Agent((string)agent.Attribute("name"), (string)agent.Attribute("name"), null)),
                        XElem = agent
                    };
            foreach (var agent in agents)
            {
                cell.TreeNodeObj.AddChild(agent.TreeNodeObj);
                var nas =
                    from na in agent.XElem.Elements("node-agent")
                    select new
                    {
                        TreeNodeObj = new TreeNode<Element>
                            (new NodeAgent((string)na.Attribute("name"), (string)na.Attribute("name"), null)),
                        XElem = agent
                    };
                foreach (var na in nas)
                {
                    agent.TreeNodeObj.AddChild(na.TreeNodeObj);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide the exp.xml or at least some sample data from it so people can mess around with the real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer this fully without sample data and actual types, but I would refactor it like below.

From the original example, I'm assuming we don't want to mess with the constructors of the entities (`Agent` etc), and that we want to retain the separate "`TreeNode<T>`" model, putting our entities inside the tree (rather than changing the entities to model things as associated collections). I've also assumed that we can take more liberties with `TreeNode<T>` than we can with the entities, so I've introduced a constructor that accepts `IEnumerable<...>`, since this allows use with LINQ sub-queries:

```
XElement ops = XElement.Load(@"c:\temp\exp.xml");
Tree<Element> domain = new Tree<Element>(
    from cell in ops.Elements("cell")
    select new TreeNode<Element>(
        new Cell(
            (string)cell.Attribute("name"),
            (string)cell.Attribute("name"), null
        ),
        from agent in cell.Elements("agent")
        select new TreeNode<Element>(
            new Agent(
                (string)agent.Attribute("name"),
                (string)agent.Attribute("name"), null
            ),
            from na in agent.Elements("node-agent")
            select new TreeNode<Element>(
                new NodeAgent(
                    (string)na.Attribute("name"),
                    (string)na.Attribute("name"), null
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

With framework code below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
class Tree<T>
{
    public TreeNode<T> Root { get; set; }
    public Tree() { }
    public Tree(IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> children)
    {
        Root = new TreeNode<T>(children);
    }
}
class TreeNode<T>
{
    private List<TreeNode<T>> children;
    public IList<TreeNode<T>> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (children == null) children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
            return children;
        }
    }
    private readonly T value;
    public TreeNode() { }
    public TreeNode(T value) { this.value = value; }
    public TreeNode(T value, IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> children)
            : this(children)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public TreeNode(IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> children)
    {
        children = new List<TreeNode<T>>(children);
    }
}
class Element { }
class Cell : Element {
    public Cell(string x, string y, string z) { }
}
class Agent : Element {
    public Agent(string x, string y, string z) { }
}
class NodeAgent : Element {
    public NodeAgent(string x, string y, string z) { }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XElement ops = XElement.Load(@"c:\temp\exp.xml");
        Tree<Element> domain = new Tree<Element>(
            from cell in ops.Elements("cell")
            select new TreeNode<Element>(
                new Cell(
                    (string)cell.Attribute("name"),
                    (string)cell.Attribute("name"), null
                ),
                from agent in cell.Elements("agent")
                select new TreeNode<Element>(
                    new Agent(
                        (string)agent.Attribute("name"),
                        (string)agent.Attribute("name"), null
                    ),
                    from na in agent.Elements("node-agent")
                    select new TreeNode<Element>(
                        new NodeAgent(
                            (string)na.Attribute("name"),
                            (string)na.Attribute("name"), null
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without your classes and source xml, it's quite hard to provide you with the exact code you're after, but here's how I like to structure my XML parsing:

```
XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(@"<a id=""7""><b><c name=""foo""/><c name=""bar""/></b><b/><b2/></a>");
var ae = d.Root;

var a = new A
    {
        Id = (int)ae.Attribute("id"),
        Children = new List<B>(ae.Elements("b").Select(be => new B
        {
            Children = new List<C>(be.Elements("c").Select(ce => new C
            {
                Name = (string)ce.Attribute("name")
            }))
        }))
    };
```

Given the xml:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c name="foo"/>
    <c name="bar"/>
  </b>
  <b/>
  <b2/>
</a>
```

and the classes:

```
class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> Children { get; set; }
}
class B
{
    public List<C> Children { get; set; }
}
class C
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```